# Consultar usuário PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, select

Para quem estiver com a duvida como eu tinha, abaixo vou deixar o código já pronto, apenas altere para seu projeto. O código e simplismente saber o usuário logado e dizer o nome dele em PHP PDO. Caso seu projeto seja por cookie dara certo, se for session adapte seu código ao meu.

//NOME USUARIO

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM nomedasuatabela WHERE email='$login_cookie'"; 
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $login_cookie, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Se quiser responder a própria pergunta não tem problema, basta separar o texto da pergunta e o da resposta nos respectivos campos, agora pergunta e resposta somente no área/campo de "pergunta" não é válido. Tem um erro aí no seu código vc não pode associar um bind se ele não existe na instrução SQL. O site funciona diferente de um fórum veja as diferenças na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) se tiver alguma dúvida avise, pode chamar um usuário especifico assim `@nomeDoUsuario`.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não é uma pergunta propriamente dita, mas sim uma dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente a consulta que colocou não esta correta;
Creio que o que esta querendo fazer ai é pegar um email que esta no cookie do navegador e passando para este método.

A maneira mais correta seria:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM nomedasuatabela WHERE email = :email"; 
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $login_cookie, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Ou

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM nomedasuatabela WHERE email = ?"; 
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $login_cookie, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Estou levando em consideração que o email ali é uma string.

Comment: Sim está e maneira que achei, quando usuario fazer login ou cadastro automatico se cria um cookie, pelo cookie eu pego o nome no banco de dados e mostro na tela, mas obrigado, editarei meu projeto.

Comment: Não entendi esse "1". $stmt->bindParam(1, $login_cookie, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Esse `1` que é colocado ai é para falar o parametro que é passado, em um ordem. Muitas vezes quando você não passa por referencia (`:parametro`) você pode colocar pela ordem que é chamado, por exemplo:

Você tem 2 parametros, então entraria:

$stmt->bindParam(1, $parametroUm, PDO::PARAM_STR)
$stmt->bindParam(2, $parametroDois, PDO::PARAM_STR)